# Wordpress: show recent posts from diffrent wordpress sites (sub-domains)

Tags: wordpress, subdomain, posts, multisite

I am developing a WordPress site to show posts from different WordPress installation (Sub domains), this new WordPress installation would be the main website.

Each source website is a sub-domain like news.example.com, sports.example.com, cars.example.com, business.example.com etc.

What i want to do is to show recent posts from above sub-domains to  main website www.example.com.

> Whether i can use some thing like MULTI-SITE WordPress installation,
>   without affecting sub-domains.

I am good in php but new to WordPress.

> I am also thinking to use plugin feedWordPress (this help in reading
>   posts from other WordPress installation feeds and store in local
>   installation), to pull posts from sub-domains to the main site
>   database.

Please suggest the best suitable method.

Answer (score 0):

1) You can use [RSS FEED](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Feeds)

```
$feed = simplexml_load_file('http://your-sub-domain.com/feed/');
$posts = $feed->channel;
foreach ( $posts->item as $post  ) {
    echo '<a href="'.$post->link.'">'.$post->title.'</a>';
}
```

2) or use [WP API](http://wp-api.org/)

```
$posts = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://your-sub-domain.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?filter[posts_per_page]=6&filter[orderby]=date'));
foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
    echo '<a href="'.$post->link.'">'.$post->title->rendered.'</a>';
}
```